# Read strings into Jena Model

Tags: java, jena, apache-jena

I have some Triples stored in a string like

```
String st =
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/53debf646ad3465872522651> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/end> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/1407106906391> . 
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/53debf676ad3465872522655> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/foi> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/SpatialThing> .
```

Now I am using JENA to read the same string as

```
           Model md= ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
            InputStream in = IOUtils.toInputStream(st,"UTF-8");
            System.out.println(in.available());
            try{
                md.read(in, "N-TRIPLES");
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          System.out.println("model size:"+md.size());
```

I know that the string is available to InputStream, but model size is always printed as 0. So  `md. read` is not working properly. How should I debug it?

**Update**
It throws exception as

```
org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: 1, col: 7 ] Element or attribute do not match QName production: QName::=(NCName':')?NCName
```

I think syntax is fine according to N-TRIPLES. Where is the issue?
For debugging purpose I have placed a small program at [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fhrg4mpvklq5675/dataread.java?dl=0)

Comment: It looks as if you are parsing for URLs (which point to models) not the models themselves. Hence the result is "empty".

Comment: @Drux But I think each triple in string should be considered as valid statement. Hence model should be able to read it.

Comment: I see, so those URLs are for resources. Which syntax is this meant to be. E.g. N3 would expect extra brackets and dots ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the three-argument `read()` method and pass `null` as the second argument (base uri).

```
static String triples =
    "<http://dbpedia.org/resource/53debf646ad3465872522651> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/end> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/1407106906391> ." +
    "\n<http://dbpedia.org/resource/53debf676ad3465872522655> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/foi> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/SpatialThing> .";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel()
        .read(IOUtils.toInputStream(triples, "UTF-8"), null, "N-TRIPLES");
    System.out.println("model size: " + model.size());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your RDF syntax is a bit off. If you are parsing N3 or Turtle, then try changing your string to this:

```
String st =
"<http://dbpedia.org/resource/53debf646ad3465872522651> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/end> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/1407106906391> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/53debf676ad3465872522655> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/foi> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/SpatialThing> ."
```

Comment: While using the above string format and putting the serializations as N3 and TURTLE.  it still shows size as 0

Comment: @haroonrashid Specify the actual syntax when parsing the model. (Your comment mentions it, but your code does not.)

Comment: @Drux, I specified it, but still it is not able to the statements read into model.